# What does := mean in Go?

Tags: go, colon-equals

I'm following this tutorial, specifically exercise 8:

http://tour.golang.org/#8

---

```
package main

import "fmt"

func swap(x, y string) (string, string) {
    return y, x
}

func main() {
    a, b := swap("hello", "world")
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

Specifically what does the `:=` mean? Searching for Go documentation is very hard, ironically.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I guess it's a case of knowing what to search for. I tried `go := meaning`, `golang :=` and nothing relevant came up.

Comment: For what it's worth, it wasn't where I usually looked for Go resources/specification

Comment: If you run into something in the language that you don't understand, instead of googling (which is definitely not going to work well for punctuation), just pop open [golang.org/ref/spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec) and search there. That's the actual spec for the language, and it's not very large. Second occurrence of ":=" on the page is precisely what you want.

Comment: It's explained [in the tutorial](http://tour.golang.org/#12)

Comment: I came here from google, so the question might not be entirely invalid.

Comment: It's just a shorthand for declaring and initializing a variable (or multiple variables when using a comma). The types are inferred from the values passed in. So in your case, you would have two variables `a` and `b`, both of type `string`, initialized with the values returned from `swap("hello", "world")`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[A short variable declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) uses the syntax:

```
ShortVarDecl = IdentifierList ":=" ExpressionList .
```

It is a shorthand for a regular variable declaration with initializer expressions but no types:

Answer (score 8):

Keep on going to page 12 of the tour!

> A Tour of Go
>
> [Short variable declarations](http://tour.golang.org/#12)
>
> Inside a function, the := short assignment statement can be used in
>   place of a var declaration with implicit type.
>
> (Outside a function, every construct begins with a keyword and the :=
>   construct is not available.)

Answer (score 7):

As others have explained already, := is for both declaration, and assignment, whereas = is for assignment only.

For example, var abc int = 20 is the same as abc := 20.

It's useful when you don't want to fill up your code with type or struct declarations.

Comment: Take my comment as a little joke: no aswer should start with "As others have explained already...", right? 

Answer (score 5):

The `:=` syntax is shorthand for declaring and initializing a variable, example `f := "car"` is the short form of `var f string = "car"`

**The short variable declaration operator(`:=`) can only be used for declaring local variables**. If you try to declare a global variable using the short declaration operator, you will get an error.

Refer [official documentation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) for more details

Comment: You could add a link to the official doc, like the accepted answer. I also think that this symbol can only be used in local variables, right? If that's true, you could add that.

Comment: @FerranMaylinch Thanks for the suggestions to make it more accurate ..

Comment: It's funny that you got a negative vote, and then someone wrote the same answer 

Answer (score 1):

:= is not an operator. It is a part of the syntax of the Short variable declarations clause.

more on this: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations

Answer (score 0):

According to my book on Go, it is just a short variable declaration statement
exactly the same as

```
var s = ""
```

But it is more easy to declare, and the scope of it is less expansive. A := var decleration also can't have a type of interface{}. This is something that you will probably run into years later though

Comment: The only difference between the two is that var can be used in a global scope. You can also use `var` in functions, and it'll behave exactly the same as `:=`. Also, you can use the `interface{}` type with `var` declarations.

Answer (score -2):

:= represents a variable, we can assign a value to a variable using :=.